# How to add another primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that has primary keys

```
CompanyID
ClientID
ReportName
```

I need to add a column that is an additional key and an incremented ID.

```
alter table Exports
add id int identity(1,1)
```

How do I write the statement to make this a key as well?

Comment: You can't have 2 Primary Keys! [It says so here too!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys)

Comment: What you may have currently is a *composite* primary key. If that's the case, we need you to clearly say whether you're trying to *add another column to that composite key* or whether you're wishing to declare a *separate* secondary key. As Radu says, there's only 1 PK per table.

Comment: He can add another column to the existing PrimaryKey, although with an identity column the other columns should have an unique index instead of being part of the primary key

Comment: Sounds like you are applying a surrogate key in the form of an IDENTITY PK. As stated, you can convert your current PK as a secondary composite UNIQUE INDEX and add your new IDENTITY column, however, you may need to think about re-creating any existing FK's using the new PK.

Comment: What you can also do to simulate another primary key is add a unique constraint per this new column that you create. But, by creating an identity column you pretty much have this set up already. The only major difference between an IDENTITY column and a UNIQUE constraint is that a unique constraint automatically builds a non-clustered index on that column (or unique constraint key) behind the scenes, so you would get a little more benefit from that.

Comment: _"I need to add a column that is an additional key and an incremented ID."_ Why? This may well be an X/Y question.

Answer (score -2):

You can have only 1 primary key or identity column in each table in SQL Server.

If you want to have one more column as primary key, then you may use the combination of the columns as the primary key.

Or you can set the constraints `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` to the columns so that they will act same as a primary key (but these columns can't be referred as foreign keys)

In case of auto incremental columns (identity), you can only have 1 identity column per table. It can also be set as a primary key. Otherwise, if you need multiple columns as auto-increment, then probably you can use a calculated column, a trigger or a `sequence` object from which you may fetch the values for each record

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect (and is contradicted by your second). You can have multiple columns in a primary key.

Comment: Updated the answer @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: And a foreign key can refer to a unique constraint; it is not limited to primary keys.